# Pasting vector contents as objects' names

Tags: r

Let's say I have two objects in my environment, `obj_1` and `obj_2`. And I also have a vector of their names `vec <- c("obj_1", "obj_2")`.

Now, I want to exclude something from that vector, let's say `vec <- vec[-c(2)]`, and then to pass the rest to another custom function -- i.e. somehow paste the vector contents the way that it would correspond to an actual object in an my environment.

How can it be done?

Comment: What is your expected output?  In your example, there are two elements in the `vec` and you want to exclude that?

Comment: `obj_1` passed as a name of an actual object, not a string. (I exclude another object by its position in a vector).

Comment: Please post both exampe input and expected output. This is currently quite unclear.

Comment: If you need to extract the values from the string, just do `mget(vec)`

Comment: @akrun, the point is, I do not need *values* of the objects in question, I need *names* (actually, it''s a bunch of separate data frames which are needed to be passed to another function exactly as a bunch of separate data frames). `mget`, on the other hand, produces a list of values of objects, which doesn't fit me...

Comment: Then, show the expected output

Comment: Expected output is `obj_1` refering to an object in an environment. I.e., if passed to a function, the function will refer to that object. Like `head(some_way_to_get_that_name(vec))` will actually print a head of `obj_1`.

Comment: If you don't want to use `get` and `assign`, you could do something like `.GlobalEnv[[vec[[1]]]]` (it would be better to have those objects in a dedicated environment instead of the global environment). Anyway, your question is quite unclear and there is probably a more canonical solution.

Comment: Not sure if OP's original intention was same as mine, but this question has just solved my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up your environment:

```
obj_1 <- 1:10
obj_2 <- 11:20
vec <- c("obj_1", "obj_2")
```

Get the name of the object that you want:

```
vec <- vec[-2]
```

Get the object:

```
get(vec)
```

Also look at `mget`

Comment: Won't it be values of `obj_1`, not actually `obj_1`? Sorry I wasn't clear enough, my expected output is `obj_1` refering to an object in an environment. I.e., if passed to a function, the function will refer to that object. Like `head(some_way_to_get_that_name(vec))` will actually print a head of `obj_1`.

Comment: wouldn't `head(get(vec))` give you the desired results?

Comment: Well, `head` may be the wrong example then, sorry again :). The point is I need to pass several data frames to a function. Not their values, not a list of their values but exactly data frames as data frames present in an environment.

Comment: can't you pass it in a list then? like `list(dataframeA, dataframeB)` etc

Comment: if you pass it as a list, you can do something like `list(get(nameofdfA), get(nameofdfB))`

Comment: No, I can't. It should be passed as separate data frames (as `...` argument of that custom function). Nothing I can really change here.

Comment: so do you want to pass the dataframe or name of dataframe?

Comment: Output should be a name referring to an object. The funniest thing I remember doing that before... but damn me if I remember *how*...

Comment: are you looking for `quote`?

Comment: Sorry for the mess, `get` (or `eval(as.name())` for that matter) was actually OK, just had to write a little wrapper... Thanks for your help and patience :).